# Xcode 11 console spew

Tags: xcode, logging, console

I've noticed some strange spew in the console after updating to Xcode 11.
Has anyone else seen this, or know what the issue night be.

0000000A:  0100  4          4          319

00000016:  0101  4          4          398

00000022:  0102  3          6          110

0000002E:  011A  5          8          116

0000003A:  011B  5          8          124

00000046:  0128  3          2            3

00000052:  0131  2         13          132

0000005E:  0132  2         20          146

000000A8:  0100  4          4          205

000000B4:  0101  4          4          256

000000C0:  0102  3          6          268

000000CC:  0103  3          2            6

000000D8:  0106  3          2            6

000000E4:  0115  3          2            3

000000F0:  0201  4          4          274

000000FC:  0202  4          4         7301

etc

Comment: I have the same problem! <3